# Inheritance in database in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I am going to make a project in which i have

`Task Entity` and there can be several types of task and suppose all of them have different fields from each other . So how can i manage this kind of approach in sql ?

Like this

```
   Task ( abstract class ) 
   Change Engine Oil ( child class ) 
   Meet James ( child class )
```

so in above case each child class have different type of properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of having 2 tables to start with - Tasks and TaskEntityDetails.

Tasks table will have 2 columns - TaskID (Primary Key) and Task

TaskEntityDetails table will have 4 columns - ID (Primary Key), TaskID (Foreign Key), Field, Value.

Field column will store all the fields for a TaskID on rows instead of having them as separate columns.
Value column will have the value corresponding to the field for each TaskID.

Your table will look like this:

```
ID    TaskID    Field         Value
1     1         StartDate     2014-01-01
2     1         EndDate       2014-01-31
3     1         Contact       ABC
4     2         StartDate     2014-01-01
5     2         TaskName      XYZ
```

You can then use `PIVOT` operator when you want to retrieve data. In this way, you can avoid having a number of NULL values in your table.

Comment: if we consider your solution then we are going to put almost all data in `TaskEntityDetail` table . is this a good practice ?

Comment: What i suggested is the basic structure to start with. You can always go ahead and have a separate table for Fields as well and have their keys in the main table.

Comment: Its on the same lines as the above example. Similar to TaskID, you will have FieldID (Foreign Key) in place of Field and there will be a separate table Fields having 2 columns - FieldID (Primary Key) and Field Name. The table mentioned above will remain as your master data table, similar to fact tables in data warehouse.

Comment: thanks , i would prefer first one as second approach will increase a join for each query of task . Anyway thanks